# jquery selectors getting unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to get the row contents by selecting the tr element which has a unique id.

This is what i have so far, i'm fairly new to this, and really unsure why this isn't working.

```
var value = $('tr#'+idd).find('input[type=text]').map(function() { return $(this).attr("value"); }).get();
```

I've tried changing the id so it's not unique and it does receive data. So just confused why this statement doesn't.

Any help is appreciated

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($entrys))
{
    echo "<tr id='" . $record['id'] . "'>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' id='id' name='id' value=" . $record['id'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' id='make' name='make' value=" . $record['make'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' id='fuel' name='fuel' value=" . $record['fuel'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' id='transmission' name='transmission' value=" . $record['transmission'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' id='size' name='size' value=" . $record['size'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' id='doors' name='doors' value=" . $record['doors'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='hidden' id='hidden' name='hidden' value=" . $record['id'] . " ></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<button name='update' onclick=edit('".$record['id']."') >Edit</button>";
    echo "<td>" . "<button id='delete' name='delete' onclick=del('".$record[id]."') value=" . $row . " >Delete</button>  </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Define `not working`.

Comment: I've then used alert(value); and this displays an empty message.

Comment: All ID's should be unique, period!

Comment: var lol = $('tr#row').find('input[type=text]').val(); i tried this and it only returns one value. i need it to get all the input fields for the tr element.

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure

Comment: I've posted the table structure. it's being created using php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line:

```
echo "<td>" . "<button id='delete' name='delete' onclick=del('".$record[id]."') value=" . $row . " >Delete</button>  </td>";
```

`.$record[id]."` - should be `.$record['id']."` like the others.

Comment: @MarkAmery Updated with a more relevant answer.  I misread the question, just wasn't sure why OP thought making ids not unique would improve it.

Comment: Yeah it should be, that function still works though, but have changed it.